# How to determine needed PSU rating for given hardware setup?

Tags: power-supply

Here's the PC I'm going to buy:

- INTEL Core i5 3570 - 3,4 GHz - Cache L3 6 Mb - Socket LGA 1155 (BX80637I53570)
- GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 660 OC - 2 GB GDDR5 - PCI-Express 3,0 (GV-N660OC-2GD)
- SEAGATE Disco duro interno Barracuda 7200.14 ST1000DM003 3,5" - 1 TB
- MSI B75MA-E33 - Socket 1155 - Chipset B75 - Micro ATX
- SANDISK SSD interno Ultra Plus - 128 Gb (SDSSDHP-128G-G25)
- 2 x KINGSTON Memoria de PC HyperX blu RED Series 8 Gb DDR3-1600 PC3-12800 CL10 (KHX16C10B1R/8)
- DVD/RW DRIVE (I'll use an old IDE one, using a SATA adapter; I don't remenber the model)

Plus one Wireless PCI board.

I was thinking about buying one of these two:

- CORSAIR Alimentación para PC CX600 80 PLUS Bronze - 600 W (CP-9020048-EU)
- ADVANCE Fonte de alimentação PC MPT-6500 - 650 W

The Advance PSU is cheap and has 650 W but I have read that it might not be very good.

**How do I determine which power supply I should buy?**

Also, **how do I calculate how much power I need for these components?**

Comment: Hello user2983688, and welcome to SuperUser. Shopping recommendation questions are considered off-topic here because they tend to become obsolete quickly (even more so in computer hardware than in some other fields). I have edited your question to focus on how to make a decision yourself, rather than asking others to do it for you. If you feel I have changed the intent of your question please feel free to [edit] further, but do keep in mind [the topic scope of the site](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi. Thanks Michael, my bad :D
And thanks for the support also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using an MSI MB, you could use the MSI Power Supply Calculator found here;

http://www.msi.com/service/power-supply-calculator/

I plugged in your components and it came back with a calculation of **340 watts**.  However, that doesn't take into account future expansion, plugging in anything external into USB etc.  From experience I wouldn't go with less than **500 watts** on your spec, so either of the PSU's you mention should be powerful enough.

Comment: Thank you for that info.
I'll go with the CORSAIR CX600 80 PLUS Bronze - 600 W
Also, how do i know the "CPU Code" that is on the website?
Thanks again!

Comment: http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/cs-016552.htm

Comment: @user2983688 If you feel that this answer adequately answers your question, you should indicate so by upvoting and accepting. However, I would suggest that you wait at least a day before accepting an answer, as others may yet provide even better answers.

Comment: @sgtbeano: I don't think you could have selected the processor code on that calculator page. If you select one then the recommended minimum PSU wattage it suggests is more like 340W which sounds closer to what I would have expected, but I agree that 500W would be a sensible choice.

Comment: Ah, must have selected the wrong drop down, sorry about that - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @sgtbeano That CPU code dropdown is completely broken, at least for me - it lists two Intel S-Spec numbers, one of which is a P4, and the rest are all AMD part numbers - and doesn't change if you change all the other options.

Comment: Hmmm, that's not so good - I've used this one in the past; http://www.extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp - is it accurate for you?  I should change my answer if it is.